# Breaking the nested loop

Tags: php, loops, nested-loops

I'm having problem with nested loop. I have multiple number of posts, and each post has multiple number of images.

I want to get total of 5 images from all posts. So I am using nested loop to get the images, and want to break the loop when the number reaches to 5. The following code will return the images, but does not seem to break the loop.

```
foreach($query->posts as $post){
        if ($images = get_children(array(
                    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image'))
            ){              
                $i = 0;
                foreach( $images as $image ) {
                    ..
                    //break the loop?
                    if (++$i == 5) break;
                }               
            }
}
```

Comment: You should declare `$i = 0;` out of all loops

Comment: `break;` will stop loop in which it is used, not the outside loops too.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Unlike other languages such as C/C++, in PHP you can use the optional param of break like this:

```
break 2;
```

In this case if you have two loops such that:

```
while(...) {
   while(...) {
      // do
      // something

      break 2; // skip both
   }
}
```

`break 2` will skip both while loops.

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

This makes jumping over nested loops more readable than for example using `goto` of other languages

Comment: And it is almost as evil as goto :-) (+1 anyway)

Comment: @zerkms: i don't think... break its prettty readable

Comment: `break` - yes. `break 2` - no :-)

Comment: @zerkms Can you tell us WHY it's evil? Just saying it doesn't really help me understand why I shouldn't use it

Comment: @dKen: break 2; isn't evil use it with good indentation and no one will have problems to read your code. Other options are: (i) rewrite the code structure to avoid the use of break 2 and (ii) use of goto. Considering this alternative, `break 2` is the perfectly fine

Comment: I didn't know this thing existed.

Comment: `goto` isn't evil. dumb people regurgitate stupidity.

Comment: @r3wt if `goto` isn't evil why in PHP documentations you have that very funny story (images) at the top? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php ??? :)

Comment: @RoyShoa `goto` can be used responsibly. a good use case in my experience as far as php is concerned, is avoiding the overhead of recursion, like so: https://postimg.org/image/qrlev2elp/

Comment: Obligatory reference: [Go To Considered Harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html). Basically, `goto` almost always harms program readability / understand-ability, and is always logically unnecessary.

Comment: Obligatory reference: ["GOTO Considered Harmful" Considered Harmful](http://web.archive.org/web/20090320002214/http://www.ecn.purdue.edu/ParaMount/papers/rubin87goto.pdf). Basically, *not* using `goto` when it makes sense can lead to spaghetti code, and is sometimes logically unnecessary.

Comment: I commend you for remembering something we must have all read about way back when and immediately forgot! :-) And it's much more readable than inserting extra conditions to check if the inner loop completed.

Answer (score 3):

Use a while loop

```
<?php 
$count = $i = 0;
while ($count<5 && $query->posts[$i]) {
    $j = 0;
    $post = $query->posts[$i++];
    if ($images = get_children(array(
                    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image'))
            ){              
              while ($count < 5 && $images[$j]) { 
                $count++; 
                $image = $images[$j++];
                    ..
                }               
            }
}
?>
```