# Is there a "superbreak" in Javascript or PHP for loops?

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop, break

On many of the projects on which I work, I find that I have nested `for` loops (I will focus on PHP implementation but applies to javascript as well) that take this generic form:

```
$array1 = array(........);
$count1 = count($array1);

$invalidState = false;//An invalid state will be looked for in the innermost loop, and if found, break all the loops

for($i = 0; $i < $count1; $i++) {
    //parsing, then another loop
    $array2 = explode("needle", $array1[$i]);
    $count2 = count($array2);
    for($j = 0; $j < $count2; $j++) {
        //parsing, then sometimes even another another loop
        $array3 = explode("different-needle", $array2[$j]);
        $count3 = count($array3);
        for($k = 0; $k < $count3; $k++) {
            //check for an invalid state in $array3[$k], and break if invalid state = true; 
        }
        if ($invalidState) break;
    }
    if ($invalidState) break;
}
```

To reiterate, if an invalid state is found in the innermost loop, then all the loops should break. But as far as I am aware, to break from all the loops, I must set a variable (in this case `$invalidState`), and check this in all the outer loops, and if true, then break.

Is there any kind of "super-break" where if a condition is met in the innermost loop, all outer loops will be broken?

Comment: Yes, you should check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609532/php-breaking-the-nested-loop

Comment: And to complement @luigonsec's comment, [here's the javascript way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183161/best-way-to-break-from-nested-loops-in-javascript).

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19734110/2018654

Comment: I prefer bat break or captain break, but super break is good too

Comment: @JaromandaX It's a bird ? It's a plane ? No ! It's superbreak !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count1; $i++) {
    //parsing, then another loop
    $array2 = explode("needle", $array1[$i]);
    $count2 = count($array2);
    for($j = 0; $j < $count2; $j++) {
        //parsing, then sometimes even another another loop
        $array3 = explode("different-needle", $array2[$j]);
        $count3 = count($array3);
        for($k = 0; $k < $count3; $k++) {
            break 3; 

    }
    if ($invalidState) break;
}
if ($invalidState) break;
}
```

When you write `break n` you are breaking `n` nested loops.
However, you can't `break $foo`, because this ability has been recently removed:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: This should be considered as the answer, since it truly give a response, not a workaround (return)

Comment: Actually, `break n` was removed from PHP since PHP 5.4 (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) so this example will throw syntax error on PHP 5.4+.

Comment: @Martin From the link you gave me: `5.4.0 - Removed the ability to pass in variables (e.g., $num = 2; break $num;) as the numerical argument.` but it seems that `break 3` still working

Comment: Ou, you're right, its related to only `break $var` syntax.

Comment: @Martin thank you for the observation, I learnt something new!

Answer (score 3):

Probably most easily just wrap the loop in a function and when you want to use "super-break" just use `return`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest making your outer loop its own function, and returning explicitly in the center of the loop to hard break from all the nested loops.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider this:

```
break 3; //Breaks 3 levels, so breaks outermost foreach
```

Comment: Should be `break 3;` as per the answer from @luigonsec.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `return` for this purpose